# PHPSpreadsheet dropdown item limit

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to display bunch of items in dropdown list of phpspreadsheet.
It's working if the dropdown has only 1-5 items but when I try to add list with 35 items, it's not working

Here's my code

```
    $validation = $sheet->getCell('I2')->getDataValidation();
    $validation->setType( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
    $validation->setErrorStyle( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
    $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
    $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
    $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
    $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
    $sheet->setCellValue('I2', 'Choose GL Accounts');
    $validation->setFormula1('"'.$glaccounts.'"');
```

$glaccounts has 35 items.

How can I increase the limit of the dropdown?

Comment: `$validation->setFormula1('"'.$glaccounts.'"');` needs to be `$validation->setFormula1($glaccounts);`  or `$validation->setFormula1("$glaccounts");`. Isn't it?

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie `$glaccounts`has string value `Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5.....` and so on. It's working when it has only 5 items.

Comment: Based on [DOCS](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/)  check section "Setting data validation on a cell"....... It is important to remember that any string participating in an Excel formula is allowed to be maximum 255 characters (not bytes). This sets a limit on how many items you can have in the string `"Item A,Item B,Item C"`. Therefore it is normally a better idea to type the item values directly in some cell range, say `A1:A3`, and instead use, say, `$validation->setFormula1('Sheet!$A$1:$A$3')`.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie bro sorry but i don't get it

Comment: @TristanRoss have you resolved this issue?
Please let me know I am stuck on the same issue.

Comment: Answer of @serving-quarantine-period  helped me quite a lot. Thanks